# Set component prop to const array/object or re-create each render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Curious in the performance or other benefits of using `const` variables where possible when setting a component's props verses setting them inline. Please include supporting ReactJS documentation if applicable.

Potential benefits of using const variables in my head:

- Reduced overhead creating objects on every render.
- Fewer cluttered code?
- Fewer lifecycle/render loops? (This is my main concern.)

**Example 1: Inline / Traditional**

```js
export const SomeContainer(...) => (
  <Something validators={[required(), minLength(3), maxLength(10)]} />
);
```

**Example 2: Via `const` Variables**

```js
export const SomeContainer(...) => (
  <Something validators={Validators} />
);

const Validators = [required(), minLength(3), maxLength(10)];
```

In *Example 1*, the `validators` prop is a new array on each render while in *Example 2*, a constant value is passed to the `validators` prop.

Same question with:

- inline vs. const objects ...

  - `value={{a, b, c}}`
  - `value={ConstWithABC}`
- inline vs. const callbacks ...

  - `onChange={value => setState({ x: value })}`
  - `onChange={handleChange}` (`handleChange` is an instance function/const lambda)

Answer (score 1):

React can track the state changes easily. So re-rendering the state owner component(let's call it XComponent) directly is the first point. Then, as you already know, a re-render flow will start upon all XComponent's children tree recursively.

While doing this, React will check `prop` changes to decide which children should re-render like:

1. if the `prop` is primitive, there will be a simple value comparison
2. if the `prop` is an array, function, or object(that's the place you were mentioning in your question), there will be a reference comparison directly. That's why there are two hooks for this purpose: `useMemo` and `useCallback`. These hooks help you to store the reference or value result from your in-component definitions/calculations. So, your second example most probably will not trigger a re-render because of the reference equality. And then React can stop trimming re-render tree after `<Something />` and its possible children.

I experienced this while changing a `prop` array item in the past. I saw that React didn't even realize that I changed the `prop` array's length from 3 to 2 because of the same array reference. But I was seeing that there are still 3 items on the screen.

3. if the child is a result of some iteration or mapping like:

```
const Comp1 = (props) => {
  return <div>
    {props.data.map((item) => <Comp2 key={item.id} propX={item.x}/>)}
  </div>;
};
```

then, there will be a `key` comparison for understanding which child should be added or removed from the render.
https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys
And React docs suggest that you should use a primitive type for keys to make the comparison easier.

Overall, there is a doc for a better explanation https://reactjs.org/docs/reconciliation.html

Comment: Thanks. My question actually _is_ more about React and how it considers the same array vs. a new array _with the same contents_ when deciding if a state change should trigger a re-render.

Comment: I'm sorry. I'm new here as a responder. I should ask that first. Let me update my answer

Answer (score 0):

basically your examples are all just values, I don't see much of a performance difference.

There will be a difference if you do the following, however.

```
<Something value={[1000 numbers array].reduce((a,b) => a+b))} />
```

vs

```
const someNumber = useMemo(() => [1000 numbers array].reduce((a,b) => a+b)), [1000 numbers array])
return <Something value={someNumber} />
```

In above example it's calculation x 1000, vs calculation x 1, if you were to render the page 1000 times.

and if you don't want const Validators = [...] to be re-rendered every time, you can basically put it outside the component as global const variable and it gets rendered only once.

E.g. if you want to declare a styled component, it's always advised to declare the styled component OUTSIDE the component, so that you only render it once.

And with regards to your following example.

```
inline vs. const callbacks ...
onChange={value => setState({ x: value })}
onChange={handleChange} (handleChange is an instance function/const lambda)
```

You are just referring to a single setState. What if it's function with 100lines of codes? You gonna throw that in the return clause?

**Many times, other than performance, we also consider readability. Even if writing the function within the return clause provides better performance, I will never do that.**